# Power Automate - Flow Fails InvalidTemplate- When trying to save attachment to Sharepoint Using Create File

Tags: azure-devops, power-automate, azure-boards

Here is what I am trying to do:-

I want to create a work item in Azure DevOps when an email arrives in my inbox. If the email has an attachment, I want to save that attachment in the SharePoint site folder, retrieve the link of the created file, and update the work item description with the file link.

I have created the flow but when testing, here is what the exception is coming
[image: Power Automate Exception]

I am sending this email from Gmail to my organization account. I have researched this problem in existing threads at the Power Automate community as well, but nothing seems to be fit as a potential solution to this problem. Your help in this regarding is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by creating a new flow, in this case, please make sure, you are updating the configuration of outlook email to say "Include Attachments" - "yes".

Please refer to screenshot below
[image: Power Automate Configuration]

If you will not include it, it will be treated as null, when you will be trying to create a file at SharePoint using power automate.

Hope this helps everyone.

Thanks,
Bee

Comment: Hi benz,
You could accept your answer. In this case, others could directly find the useful solution. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Vito Liu-MSFT, I accepted the answer :), can you upvote the answer haha. :)

Comment: No issues. Thanks for your sharing.